# Redirect url to another

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, amazon-ec2

I am using an AWS EC2 instance to host a website. I have an installation under /var/www/html/xyz/ dir & thus if I have to access website homepage, I have to specify link as www.example.come/xyz. I want that www.example.com should be redirected to www.example.com/xyz

Any idea how can I redirect www.example.com to www.example.com/xyz automatically (httpd config or anything similar)?

I checked online but most of the posts are related to subdomain redirects e.g. redirect admin.example.com to www.example.com which is not my issue.

Thanks!

my .htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# Some hostings require RewriteBase to be uncommented
# Example:
# Your url is http://www.yourcompany.com/xyz
# So "RewriteBase" should be:
# RewriteBase /xyz

Options -MultiViews
RewriteBase /xyz

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^api/(.*)$ [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/api/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*api/(.*)$ api.php?_d=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css|ttf|svg|eot|woff|yml|xml)$ [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} store_closed.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\/(.*)$ $2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new .htaccess file with following code

`RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
 RewriteRule (.*) /xyz/ [R=301]`

you should have mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: In his .htaccess file he is using `RewriteBase /xyz` so this won't work. You perhaps wanted to tell him he should create a new .htaccess file in the webroot directory with your content :)

Comment: @hakre .htaccess file was added post answer. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Do you mean if I remove RewriteBase from the file & use niteshd22@ changes it would work? If I create a new .htaccess file then what about other contents .htaccess file contains?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to change the document root of your site. If you are running Ubuntu, you should have a file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/YOUR_SITE.conf` (maybe `default.conf`). Just edit it and change the `DocumentRoot` to point to your subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your htaccess file, this will redirect the user to the subfolder without changing th URL www.domain.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^subdir/ /subdir%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Another method with URL www.domain.com/subdir

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /subdir[L]
```

Comment: I tried both options mentioned above & restarted httpd, but they don't work.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^subdir/ /subdir%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) /subdir/ [R=301]

RewriteRule ^$ /subdir[L]

Comment: `Redirect 301 /path/to-old-url    http://www.cyourdomain.com/path/to-Try this new-url`

Comment: I gave Redirect 301 http://www.example.com/ http://www.example.com/xyz
but still when I type http://www.example.com, it still doesn't get redirected.

Is there another way to verify that any of my changes to .htaccess are getting reflected or not

Comment: you have specified the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\/(.*)$ $2 [L]`  two times, there is no need to write it again

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in Root/.htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /xyz
```

This will redirect

```
http://example.com
```

to

```
http://example.com/xyz
```

And you want to **Rewrite**  http://example.com/foo to  http://example.com/xyz/foo , you can use mod_rewrite :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^/?((?!xyz).*)$ /xyz/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I added RedirectMatch rule but doesn' work.

I restarted httpd daemon again after changing the rule but still I am not getting redirected. 
I am making changes under:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

...

Comment: @AFH Can you post your currunt htaccess file in question?

Comment: I have added file contents to the question description

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help !

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

or this

```
Redirect 301 /path/to-old-url http://www.cyourdomain.com/path/to-Try this new-url
```